# Align shape to center of textview on Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I need to center a circle shape to the center of a Textview in a RelativeLayout,
i already tried with `android:gravity` but is not working this this.

This is the actual layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rvSincronizado"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rvSincronizado"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvetMarca"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/rvetMarca"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvMarca"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetMarca"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvetModelo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/rvetModelo"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rvMarca"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvModelo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetModelo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvetSerie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvetMarca"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/rvetSerie"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvSerie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvetModelo"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetSerie"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[This is how currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBtAa.png)

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot accomplish what you're trying to do using `RelativeLayout`. It only allows you to specify one rule for vertical alignment (e.g. `layout_alignTop` or `layout_alignBottom`) and there's no "alignCenterVertically" or similar.

You could instead try using `ConstraintLayout`, which *does* allow you to specify multiple constraints for vertical alignment. You have to convert all of your `android:layout_below` attributes to `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`, and you have to convert all of your `android:layout_toRightOf` attrs to `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf`, but the conversion is overall pretty simple. Once you've done that, you can add these two constraints to your circle ImageView:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rvSincronizado"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="PRENSA"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/rvSincronizado"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetMarca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/rvetMarca"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDescripcion"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvMarca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDescripcion"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvetMarca"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/rvetModelo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDescripcion"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/rvMarca"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvDescripcion"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvetModelo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetSerie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/rvetSerie"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvetMarca"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvSerie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvetModelo"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvetSerie"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in linearLayout and adjust it with bit of a margin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rvSincronizado"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvDescripcion"
                android:background="@android:drawable/presence_away"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvDescripcion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="werwerwerwerwerwerwer"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetMarca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lnDescripcion"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvMarca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lnDescripcion"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetMarca"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lnDescripcion"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rvMarca"
            android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lnDescripcion"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetModelo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvetSerie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rvetMarca"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvSerie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rvetModelo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rvetSerie"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: like this]